# Cohort Analysis with RedShift by Month

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to build a cohort analysis for monthly retention but experiencing challenge getting the **Month Number column** right. The month number is supposed to return month(s) user transacted i.e 0 for registration month, 1 for the first month after registration month, 2 for the second month until the last month but currently, it returns negative month numbers in some cells.

It should be like this table:

```
cohort_month  total_users   month_number  percentage 
----------  ----------- --  ------------  ---------  
   January      100              0            40
   January      341              1            90
   January      115              2            90
   February     103              0            73
   February     100              1            40
   March        90               0            90
```

Here is the SQL:

```
with cohort_items as (
  select
    extract(month from insert_date) as cohort_month,
    msisdn as user_id
  from mfscore.t_um_user_detail where extract(year from insert_date)=2020
  order by 1, 2
),


user_activities as (
  select
    A.sender_msisdn,
    extract(month from A.insert_date)-C.cohort_month  as month_number
  from mfscore.t_wm_transaction_logs A
  left join cohort_items C ON A.sender_msisdn = C.user_id
  where extract(year from A.insert_date)=2020
  group by 1, 2
),

cohort_size as (
  select cohort_month, count(1) as num_users
  from cohort_items
  group by 1
  order by 1
),

B as (
  select
    C.cohort_month,
    A.month_number,
    count(1) as num_users
  from user_activities A
  left join cohort_items C ON A.sender_msisdn = C.user_id
  group by 1, 2
)

select
  B.cohort_month,
  S.num_users as total_users,
  B.month_number,
  B.num_users * 100 / S.num_users as percentage
from B
left join cohort_size S ON B.cohort_month = S.cohort_month
where B.cohort_month IS NOT NULL
order by 1, 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the RANK window function is the right solution. So the idea is to assigne a rank to months of user activities for each user, order by year and month.

Something like:

```
WITH activity_per_user AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        event_date,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY DATE_PART('year', event_date) , DATE_PART('month', event_date) ASC) AS month_number
    FROM user_activities_table
    )
```

RANK number starts from 1, so you may want to substract 1.

Then, you can group by user_id and month_number to get the number of interactions for each user per month from the subscription (adapt to your use case accordingly).

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    month_number,
    COUNT(1) AS n_interactions
FROM activity_per_user
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Here is the documentation:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_RANK.html